# Bootstrap Tooltip not default

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Tooltip at an `<i></i>` icon, but the style is ugly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbMNv.png]

I want to be like in this picture (default Bootstrap)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga0ua.png]

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.mark-read-button').tooltip();
});
</script>

<i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top" class="fa fa-circle mark-read-button"></i>
```

Comment: Here's a tip for you: [matooltip.com](http://www.matooltip.com). I made it to look just like Twitter's Bootstrap only better.

Comment: Maybe your tooltip cannot fit the height of the remaining space above the target node.

Comment: Do you have jQueryUI CSS loaded after your Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: @beyst yes, i added now before, no result.

Comment: Including a jsfiddle or similar would be useful so we could see if any CSS may be overriding the default Bootstrap styles

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code it uses CDNs and a jumbotron to stop the tooltip from going off of the screen.

```
<!-- CDNs -->
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Jumbotron is to stop the tooltip from going off of the screen. -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top" class="fa fa-circle mark-read-button"></i>
</div>
<!-- The script cannot be inside another document -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>
```